# Deploying an ASP.NET web site to a remote VPS with Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, iis, automation, continuous-integration, jenkins

I am just starting to get my head wrapped around continuous deployment with Jenkins, but I am running into some roadblocks and I haven't really found very many good, definitive resources on the topic in regards to ASP.NET applications.

I have set up a local build server than successfully pulls down code from a SVN repo, and builds it OK with MSBuild. This works well so far, but now I'd like to automate pushing this compiled code to a development server.

My problem is this - from what I gather based on what I read (which may be an incorrect assumption...) is that the staging server is typically within the same network as the build server, meaning you can share network resources, servers, etc.

In my case, I want to run the Jenkins server on a remote VPS, then deploy to other remote VPSes (so, essentially individual isolated machines communicating with each other).

I have seen alot of terms, but I am very new in my Sys Admin / DevOps type skills.

So, my question is this:

1. Is it even possible to, using Jenkins on a VPS, to then deploy to any particular server I choose? (I have full access to all of them, so if its a security thing, I can fix that... but they are not within the same network/domain)
2. What is the method to achieve this? I've seen xcopy, Web Deployment Packages (msdeploy), batch scripts, etc. mentioned, but not really a guidance behind what to use in what situations. Are any of these methods useful to achieve my goal?

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 1):

How is your Powershell? ;) You should check out [psake](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake).

> psake is a build automation tool written in PowerShell. It avoids the
>   angle-bracket tax associated with executable XML by leveraging the
>   PowerShell syntax in your build scripts. psake has a syntax inspired
>   by rake (aka make in Ruby) and bake (aka make in Boo), but is easier
>   to script because it leverages your existent command-line knowledge.
>
> psake is pronounced sake – as in Japanese rice wine. It does NOT rhyme
>   with make, bake, or rake.

Comment: Heh, haven't had but a passing glance at Powershell, but I'm not opposed to getting my hands dirty with it :) I might be way off base, but would this be a bit much if I have Jenkins building everything A-OK, and I just want to move files to a remote server? Or am I overlooking the obvious?

Comment: Sure. I have seen Jenkins setup to just create ZIP packages after each successful build, then you can push a particular ZIP to production for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your files to the target server through SSH. Jenkins do support transfers through SSH. All you need to do is setting up a SSH server ex : [CopSSH](https://www.itefix.net/content/copssh-free-edition) and a user account with admin permissions. and configuring the Jenkins to transfer through SSH.

- Create host configurations in the main Jenkins configuration
- Add an SSH Server
- Add the public key to the remote server (the build server)
- Click "Test Configuration"
- Save
- Configure a job to Publish Over SSH (Post Build Action)
- Add Transfer Set.

Refer [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) For More details